# DT bug : Retain previous selected rows when data changes

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In shiny, DT retains the previous selected rows when data source changes. In the code below, when you select rows from the table and then change drop down value, it still returns index of previous selected rows (from previous drop down value). This seems to be a bug in DT library. I am clueless in fixing it. I want to store all the selected rows and then show sum in the `valueboxoutput` based on the selected rows. Is also there an option to keep rows selected as it is in blue?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

# FETCH DATA
mydata = mtcars
mydata$id = 1:nrow(mydata)

#Dashboard header carrying the title of the dashboard
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard")

######################
# Dashboard Sidebar
######################

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    selectInput(
      "hyp",
      "Select:", 
      list(
        'All','drat','wt'
      ) , 
      selected =  "All", selectize = TRUE)
  )
)

# Dashboard Body

frow1 <- fluidRow(
  valueBoxOutput("value1")
)





frow2 <- fluidRow(
  box(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"), width = 12)
)

# combine the two fluid rows to make the body
body <- dashboardBody(frow1, frow2)

####################
# Dashboard Page
###################
ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Model', header, sidebar, body, skin='purple')

####################
# SERVER
###################

d = data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dd = reactiveValues(select = NULL, select2 = NULL)

  # Render Table
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(test(), rownames= FALSE, extensions = c('FixedHeader'),
                  filter = 'top', 
                  selection=list(mode = 'multiple'), 
                  options = list( autoWidth = TRUE,
                                  scrollX = TRUE, 
                                  orderClasses = TRUE,
                                  pageLength = 50, 
                                  fixedHeader = TRUE,
                                  dom = 'Bfrtip'
                  ),escape=F)
  }
  )


  proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable')

  test <- reactive({
    if(input$hyp == 'All') {
      result = mydata
    } else {
      result = mydata %>% dplyr::filter(UQ(as.name(input$hyp)) <= 3)
    }
    return(result)
  })


  mt = reactiveValues(ndt = NULL)

  observe({
    if (length(input$mytable_rows_selected) >0) {  
    mt$ndt<- test()[input$mytable_rows_selected,]
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$hyp, {freezeReactiveValue(input, "mytable_rows_selected")})

  proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable')
  observe({print(input$mytable_rows_selected)})
  observe({print(mt$ndt)})

  #creating the valueBoxOutput content
  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({
    c_a = sum(mydata[mt$ndt[["id"]],"mpg"], na.rm = T)
    valueBox(
      formatC(c_a, format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,'Total MPG'
      ,icon = icon("th",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "purple")
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

**Update**

I managed to fix it partially. Issues I am facing now - When I unselect row, it does not change the sum calculation. Also I want all the selected rows remain highlighted.

```
  mt = reactiveValues(ndt = NULL)
  ft = reactiveValues(pa = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$mytable_rows_selected, {
    mu = data.frame(n = input$mytable_rows_selected, stringsAsFactors = F)
    mt$ndt<- test()[as.numeric(mu$n),]
    ft$pa = rbind(ft$pa, mt$ndt)
    ft$pa <- distinct(ft$pa, .keep_all = TRUE)
  }
  )

  #creating the valueBoxOutput content
  output$value1 <- renderValueBox({
    c_a = sum(ft$pa[,"mpg"], na.rm = T)
    valueBox(
      formatC(c_a, format="d", big.mark=',')
      ,'Total MPG'
      ,icon = icon("th",lib='glyphicon')
      ,color = "purple")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overall you need to clear `ft$pa` if no rows is selected now, for this your observer need to react for NULL values in `input$mytable_rows_selected` (this argument `ignoreNULL = FALSE` will help). I do simple changes to your `observeEvent`

```
observeEvent(input$mytable_rows_selected, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    mu = data.frame(n = input$mytable_rows_selected, stringsAsFactors = F)
    mt$ndt<- test()[as.numeric(mu$n),]
    ft$pa = rbind(ft$pa, mt$ndt)
    ft$pa <- distinct(ft$pa, .keep_all = TRUE)

    #clear reactive dataframe
    if (is.null(input$mytable_rows_selected))
      ft$pa <- ft$pa[-1,]
  })
```